# UPDATE two tables in MySQL using JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

i have problem with **update** when use **join** (in **php**)

for example i have two table (t1 , t2)

1. t1 -> list person
2. t2 -> list store

I want to update person who is on a specific list

mySQL code :

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.attr = '852'
FROM t1 join t2 ON t1.list = t2.id
WHERE
t1.attr = '220' AND t2.type = '90'
```

why this code not work?
plz help me...

Comment: 'why this code not work' - because it's sqlserver syntax. For mysql syntax see 'Multiple-table syntax:' here - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Comment: See these page is wel very simple https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-update-join/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE t1
JOIN t2 ON t1.list = t2.id
SET t1.attr = '852'
WHERE t1.attr = '220' 
  AND t2.type = '90'
```